# How to make Tomcat to accept a cookie and then allow user to the website?

Tags: node.js, express, tomcat, single-sign-on

I have a tomcat server instance running on say port 470 of my machine. And there is a Node Js express server running on the port 443(HTTPS). User will be directed to my website through a SSO implementation handled by Node js framework. once user is authorized they will be redirected to the port 470 on the same server.

Now the problem is if user enters serverip:470 , he can by pass the SSO implementation and directly visit the homepage. How do I block user to not do that ?

Node Js is redirecting the user to tomcat by posting the cookie from the SSO. Can Tomcat read that cookie and authenticate the user ? Please let me know how to solve this .